# For a strictly increasing function $f$, prove that $f(x)=cx, x\in\mathbb Q\implies f(x)=cx,x\in\mathbb R$.

Tags: calculus

> For a strictly increasing function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, prove:
>
> If $f(x)=cx$ for $x\in\mathbb Q$, then $f(x)=cx$ for $x\in\mathbb R$.

I found this statement on M.SE. How can I prove its truth?

Comment: Hint: monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: It strongly depends on how you've defined real numbers. If you're saying a real number is, for instance, a subset of $\mathbb Q$ which is downward-closed and bounded above, as in a Dedekind cut, then this is really easy. If it's defined as the limit of a Cauchy sequence of rationals, then it's somewhat different.

Comment: I think $f$ doesn't need to be *strictly* increasing. The result holds if $f$ is assumed to be nondecreasing and $c \neq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $ x \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q} $. Then if $ p $ and $ q $ are any two rational numbers such that $ p < x < q $, we must have $ f(p) < f(x) < f(q) $, or equivalently, $ p < \dfrac{f(x)}{c} < q $. However, this implies that $ \dfrac{f(x)}{c} = x $, so we get $ f(x) = c x $.

**Note**: The denseness of $ \Bbb{Q} $ in $ \Bbb{R} $ is required here. We also assume $ c > 0 $.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Given $x \in \mathbb{R}$, consider an increasing sequence $q_n \nearrow x$ of rational numbers and a decreasing sequence $r_n \searrow x$ of rational numbers, and use the fact that $c q_n \leq f(x) \leq c r_n$.